# How to select all rows below cell that contain certain data until certain text is encountered?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have an excel file containing data of list of farmers of many villages with invoice number of certain year. I tried to filter based on Year of the invoice but I am having trouble in selecting all the farmers which falls on that Year and also the Village they are from . I Can filter only the Year but not the farmers . Can u please help me in Filtering these Data.

[image: Screenshot of the sheet]
[image: Screenshot of the sheet 2]

I need to filter data like this
-Village
--Year of Invoice
--List of Farmers
-Village
--Year of Invoice
--List of Farmers

Please Help me with a solution if possible.

Comment: You might need to do a data cleanup first. The way your data is arranged, it can't be filtered. You need a column for everything you want to filter. Name, Date, Village and so on. Every cell in these columns needs to be filled: For every Farmer there must be a Village name and a date in the same row. Every column may ONLY have the same data type - I mean you may not mix Farmer names and Villages in the same column.

Comment: @Prema Thank You for your suggestion , Since there as so many rows doing what you suggested and filtering will take double the time as compared to copying and pasting to a different sheet which i am currently doing since I haven't manage to filter them .

Comment: But the cleanup you just do once. Then you can apply the Filter in a few seconds each time you need to filter. The clean up will go faster if you can apply some know how.